# PHP session dat being overwritten

Tags: php, session, var

Dear all, 
I am having a php session problem.
PHP 5.2.6  MySQL 4.1.22
I have initiated a login for admin and all session data is good.
A list of users is called for user administration.
User is selected and an 'id' is passed [using GET for simplicity for now] to a user Mod page.
Session Data is good, user login name is displayed at top of page.
User data to modify is taken from database and displayed in standard fields. 
However the user data for some reason becomes the session data [user id etc etc etc]. I have renamed vars and done all i can to work this, but am unable to crack it. Does anyone have any idea on this? Thanks in advance. Q!

Comment: Can you give us a trimmed-down version of the PHP code so we can take a closer look?

Comment: tried to Chris but cant get it up. ahem. However i Think the problem may be a brace. will report back.

Comment: Chris, I was suffering from the thousand yard stare! It was a brace and i was tired and obviously suffering from a SNAFU. Thanks for the help esp in getting me to look at the braces.. take it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your braces. The problem i had was being careless and tired. sleep well, check your braces and dont be an idiot like me.